System.IO.FileNotFoundException for System.Management Assembly in WPF Application but Works Fine in Console Application
I'm a novice C# developer working with .NET 8.0. I have encountered an issue where my code works perfectly in a dedicated console application but throws an exception when included in my existing WPF application.
Issue Description:
In my console application, I can successfully use the System.Management namespace and its classes to gather system information. However, when I integrate the same code into my WPF application, I encounter the following exception:
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The file specified is not found. File name: 'System.Management, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' at KNXBoostDesktop.ProjectFileManager.WriteDebugFile() ...
Details:

Development Environment: .NET 8.0
Issue Occurrence: The problem arises when running the WPF application, while the console application runs without any issues.

Steps taken:

Verified References:
Checked that System.Management is referenced in the WPF project. The assembly version is 9.0.0.0, which matches the error message.

NuGet Package Installation:
Added System.Management package via NuGet Package Manager in the WPF project.

Clean and Rebuild:
Cleaned and rebuilt the solution to ensure all dependencies are correctly included.

Checked Output Directory:
Confirmed that System.Management.dll is present in the output directory (bin\Debug).


EDIT: SOLUTION FOUND.
Because my program needs to generate lots of folders when running, I have a function that runs on startup that deletes all folders created last time except the ones that are needed to run again. This function also removes ./runtimes/ that contains System.Management.dll. Hence, this is why the program cannot find it :)

if you "downgraded" to version 8.0 of System.Management would that help?
